# Spring: @ModelAttribute and array php

Tags: php, spring, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I need to map a PHP array to a Java bean.

This is my bean that map the form:

```
public class SearchModel{
   private String id;
   private String user;
   private List<SearchRoom> rooms;

   //get and set
}
```

Where SearchRoom is:

```
public class SearchRoom {
   private int adults;
   private int child;
   private List<Integer> childrenAge;

   //get and set
}
```

This is my Spring Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json")
public void search(@ModelAttribute SearchModel model) {
    System.out.println(model.getRooms());
}
```

And this is what i'm trying to send using PHP:

```
Array
(
    [id] => xxx
    [rooms] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [adults] => 3
                    [child] => 2
                    [childrenAges] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2
                            [1] => 5
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [adults] => 2
                    [child] => 0
                    [childrenAges] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [adults] => 2
                    [child] => 4
                    [childrenAges] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                            [1] => 4
                            [2] => 12
                            [3] => 17
                        )

                )

        )

    [user] => yyy
)
```

I got this exception:

```
Invalid property 'rooms[0][adults]' of bean class [com.giove.viaggi.hsw.models.SearchModel]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'rooms[0][adults]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [3]] with root cause
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'rooms[0][adults]' of bean class [com.giove.viaggi.hsw.models.SearchModel]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'rooms[0][adults]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [3]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:922)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:728)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:189)
```

What is a good solution to avoid that error and retrieve the correct values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved converting php array into an xml string and making my controller accept xml and converting it into my bean using jaxb

Answer (score 0):

PHP and JAVA? is it really possible? and.. why you should do this??

In my opinion it's not possible as Java and PHP are different technologies.

The error  *Invalid property 'rooms[0][adults]* tells you it can't find "rooms" array. 
It's normal, you haven't declared that array in java page but in php

Comment: It is possible: [PHP / Java Integration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.java.php)

Comment: if i remove rooms array, the other field are correctly mapped to the two String of java bean.